# linux のメモリのスワップアウト・スワップインの単位は？

Tags: linux, メモリ管理, スワップ

linux のメモリのスワップアウト・スワップインの単位は何で行われますか？

- ページ単位(だいたい 4kb) でしょうか？
- それとも、もうちょっと大きな、メモリ管理まわりの内部構造体の単位でしょうか？

というのも、スクリプト言語を扱っていると、ヒープのフラグメンテーションが発生すると思っています。フラグメンテーションであっても、スワップが上手く効いてくれれば、そこまで問題にはならないのではないか、と思いました。(十分にスワップを積む場合)その場合、 OS が何の単位でスワップするべき領域を決定しているのかがわりと重要になると思い、質問しています。

Answer (score 2):

> linux のメモリのスワップアウト・スワップインの単位

ページ単位です。

`sar -W` というコマンドにより、1秒辺りのスワップイン・スワップアウトの数が計測できるので、参考になるかと存じます。